# How to get this sound?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, replication, fl-studio, plugins

I wondered if you guys could help me to get this sound:

4:08 - 4:12

Btw I use Fl Studio 12.

Comment: Which of the sounds in that timeframe do you mean? There are a few...

Comment: It's like an electric sound with a phaser added.

Comment: Do you mean the FM synth (the mid-low 'ZZEEEOW!')? Are you asking about the specific modulations that happen to it in that timeframe, or how to achieve that voice altogether?

Comment: Yes I mean that FM synth. I'm asking mainly about getting the 'ZEOW!' sound, but with those modulations if possible. Thx.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could use a saw wave with an LFO changing the pitch at about 100Hz or so. For the exact change in pitch, you will need to experiment around....

or you just record yourself saying zeoow and pitch it up!